# how to Display foreign key table value

Tags: laravel

im trying to display name from jenis_lapors table. the following error occured in my code :
`Attempt to read property "name" on null`

here is my jenisLapor Model

```
class jenisLapor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'jenis_lapors';
    protected $fillable = [ 
        'id', 'name'
    ];
}
```

lapor Model

```
class lapor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public const Perempuan = 1;
    public const Laki = 0;

    protected $fillable = ['jenis_Lapor_id', 'name', 'jenisKelamin', 'rumah', 'pekerjaan', 'kantor', 'email', 'ktp', 'phone_number', 'subjek', 'isian', 'tanggal_kejadian', 'lokasi', 'tujuan_pengaduan'];
    public function jenis()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(jenisLapor::class);
    }
}
```

post Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        
        $laporans = lapor::with('jenis')->get();
        return view('auth.aduan.index',['laporans' => $laporans]);
    }
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($laporans as $laporan)
                                <tr>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->name }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->jenisKelamin == 1 ? 'Perempuan' : 'Laki-laki' }} </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $laporan->rumah }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->pekerjaan }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->kantor }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->email }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->ktp }} </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $laporan->phone_number }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->jenis->name }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->subjek }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->isian }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->tanggal_kejadian }} </td>
                                    <td> {{ $laporan->lokasi}} </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $laporan->tujuan }}
                                    </td>
                                    
                                    
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class ="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

[return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M9rh.png)

i checked that my jenis function not passing jenisLapor model, i have no clue what to do about this
sorry english not my first languange

Comment: maybe its `$laporan->jenis->name` this.. There is no `name` on `$laporan->jenis`

Comment: `$laporan->jenis` is also null!

Comment: you ma try to change `return $this->belongsTo(jenisLapor::class);` to `return $this->belongsTo(jenisLapor::class, 'id', 'jenis_Lapor_id');`

Comment: thanks it fixed i change it to return $this->belongsTo(jenisLapor::class, 'jenis_Lapor_id', 'id');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because Laravel assumes default foreign key as {function name}_id in a relational function. So in your case Laravel assumed jenis_id as the foreign key.

Many ways to fix the problem

1. Either change `public function jenis()` to `public function jenis_Lapor()`
2. change `return $this->belongsTo(jenisLapor::class);` to `return $this->belongsTo(jenisLapor::class, 'id', 'jenis_Lapor_id');`

Also I suggest change jenis_Lapor_id to jenis_lapor_id